# Count number of cells in range of all values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to count the distance between two cells using:

```
days = Range(price0.Rows(1), price.Rows(1)).Cells.count
```

where `price0` and price are the initial price and range of prices of interest respectively.

I want to be able to count the distance between two prices so that I can run a function only when `days > x` (where `x` is an integer). Currently, using the above code, I am unable to count the distance between 2 cells when the value of `price` is 0.

How should I change my code so that I can count the days between two ranges? Thanks!

Comment: You are talking about date, prices and you are counting cells. Can you explain better, maybe with a screenshot what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get count of cells between those two prices, You Can use `.Column` to get the first column and last column number and then simply count the cells in between.

try like this
     `days = Abs(price0.Column - price.Column)`

To count cells between two rows `days = Abs(price0.Rows(1).row - price.Rows(1).row)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need `Cells` instead of `Rows`:

```
days = Range(price0.Cells(1), price.Cells(1)).Cells.Count
```